# How can i recover .FORM files of my java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, data-recovery

I have lost the code of a java application that I've been working on for so long when my hard drive crashed. I don't have the code backed up anywhere, but I had the last generated JAR file of my application along with resources (images).

I used some online tools to get the code back using the JAR. It worked well, but I could only get the classes (java code) but not my JFrame designs which are represented by .form files, so I cannot continue working on it.

Any help please on how can I get my interfaces back? I'm using netbeans.

Comment: you did confirm that the code you have compiles and runs now, as expected?

Comment: yes the code is just perfect, compiles with 0 errors.

Comment: “my hard drive crashed” In which way? Depending on the situation it might be quicker to restore the data from the failing drive rather than rebuilding the UI. Also, Bitbucket private repositories are **free of charge,** there is no reason not to have a GIT backup there.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto i just learnt my lesson regarding backups, sure now this won't bring me my files back, but i'm still trying to recover the files from the harddrive, the laptop fall from a table to the ground and harddrive got hit hard, so when i restarted the laptop it does not recognize the harddrive and shows an error saying that no hard drive connected, i tried it in other computers and it stills unreadable and does not connect.

Comment: Ouch, that doesn't sound good. What is the output of `dmesg` after you attach the drive? (I give for granted that you will use Linux to perform the recovery part, because using another OS would be pointless)

Comment: i'm actually using Windows 7, the BIOS error says that there's no hard drive connected.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know a way to do that with Netbeans. You could try using JetBrains IntelliJ (Community edition is free to use) to do that.

Check this tutorial under "Creating Snapshots" section.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/creating-and-opening-forms.html

Edit: You need UI Designer plugin enabled.

Comment: Nothing different from netbeans there i guess, giving me the list of my java classes but can't find or view the design because .form files are not there, and in the tutorial there's no explanation on how to generate .form files for the existing classes.

Comment: @4R4C81D isn't "creating snapshots" section that's referred to in this answer just that? did you try it?

Comment: Run your class intellJ. And then you go new -> form snapshot and you take snapshot of a form from running application.

Comment: When i try to run the app, it shows me the configuration, there's an error that says: Module not specefied.  what is a module? when i open it's list to select it's empty, no module right there.